# File to import not found or unreadable with sass-json-vars

Tags: css, sass

I have integrated SASS with my project. Now i want to use variables which is define in .json file.

I have config.json and my application SASS file are in same folder

but when i try to import json in SASS it gives me error that File to import not found or unreadable

I also run the command

```
sass style.scss -r sass-json-vars
```

Comment: I don't have.Rb file to my project. I have a application which is built in Angular JS and added SASS file to it. Now using sass-json-vars i want to load json file to my project

Comment: my scss file located on css/app.json and when i import that on scss "@import app.json" but webstorm always gives error that app.json not found

Comment: Are your Sass files also located in `css/`?

Comment: yeah. Both on Css foler. Css/app.scss and css/app.json. Do i need to import using @import url(app.json)?